# Unity, C#, Network, 3D. Instantiating Prefab(Weapon) wont show on all Clients

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

I have 3 Gun Prefabs in an FPS Multiplayer.
When I spawn different prefabs I only see it on the local client.
Other clients still only see the Base Weapon GFX.
Is there a simple way for all players to see the weapon graphics which I Instantiate on the local client?

Animations, movement, rotations seem to work perfectly.
Only the currentGFX of the local weapon wont change on other clients

Here is my code for the Instantiate weapon part:

```
        public void SpawnWeapon(PlayerWeapon _weapon)
{
    currentWeapon = _weapon;

    //Instantiate the prefab
    GameObject _weaponIns = (GameObject)Instantiate(_weapon.graphics, weaponHolder, false);
//Assign  the weaponGFX BUT works only on the local client
    currentGraphics = _weaponIns.GetComponent<WeaponGraphics>();
}
```

Comment: Which version of Unity are you using? Unity Networking changed a lot in 2018

Comment: I am using 2018.2.8f1, but I am doing all the networking via NetworkManager , [Command] [ClientRpc] (Like Animations for Reloading etc),so i dont know if that changes anything in the way you would make the Instantiate visible for all clients. @LeviathanCode

Comment: In the "old school" way you had to use [Network.Instatiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network.Instantiate.html) and not Object.Instantiate that you're using now, the problem is that official reference says that Network class has been deprecated, idk what you should use with Unity 2018.2. Hope this gives you a little hint on how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to spawn weapon on the server.

you need add:

`using UnityEngine.Networking;`

in your script, then type

`[Command]` above your method and spawn object on the server like:

```
[Command] 
public void SpawnWeapon(PlayerWeapon _weapon)
{

currentWeapon = _weapon;
GameObject _weaponIns = (GameObject)Instantiate(_weapon.graphics, weaponHolder, 
false);
currentGraphics = _weaponIns.GetComponent<WeaponGraphics>();

NetworkServer.SpawnWithClientAuthority(_weaponIns, 
PLAYERS_NETWORK_IDENTITY.connectionToClient);
}
```

It will cause server to update it's data and then other clients will be updated.

Comment: Is there a reason that it does not seem to add the weapon to the variable currentWeapon, which I use to get info like Ammo and muzzleFlashes etc., on the "Local Client". Since now I can not see my weapon and get loads of Null references when I trie to play it with multiple clients connected.

Comment: You need to add `[SyncVar]` above variables , that you want to be automatically synchronized with a server if variables are simple.

Comment: By the way, if you use your weapon types like enums or constants, you can just change local variable with `[SyncVar(hook="OnWeaponChanged")] attribute and handle changing weapon in the method called OnWeaponChanged that receives weapon type and instantiate weapon there on each client.